# How does an exception handler register on a frame of the stack?

Tags: c#

Does Anybody know the article about details or memory layout for an exception handle on a frame of the stack?

Comment: What is the context? Could you please provide a little more information.

Comment: Start by reading this: http://blogs.msdn.com/cbrumme/archive/2003/10/01/51524.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The implementation details are very well hidden.  Neither Brumme's blog nor the Rotor source code give a ready answer.  One thing I know is that the try statement doesn't generate any code.  That leaves few possible approaches.  I think it is done the same way as SEH in 64-bit Windows.

I believe the JIT compiler generates a table of code addresses with a function pointer to an exception filter that's called when an exception is processed.  The throw statement invokes a stack walk that looks at the method return addresses.  The table maps a return address to the corresponding exception filter.  The exception filter decides whether the exception matches a catch clause in the method.  And transfers control to the code in the catch clause.  Notable is that the Visual Basic Catch When statement (not available in C#) is a good match with the way SEH is implemented in Windows.

I have no proof of this nor do I know any authoritative source.  It is merely a likely way it could work.